# Explicitly free memory underlying C++ iostream

Tags: c++, memory-management, iostream

I am writing a C++ application that uses an iostream instance to accumulate and digest large amounts binary data (10M+) from a web service. The stream is preferred for several reasons, but foremost of these is ease of integration with a third-party stream-based API without requiring in-memory copies when converting between types.

When I am done digesting the data, I would like to explicitly free the memory underlying the iostream instance. I am sure that the memory would be freed when the instance goes out of scope, but since I'm passing it into an API, I'm not sure that it will be handled efficiently. If I were using a stringstream I could call `std::stringstream.clear(); std::stringstream.str(std::string());`. Is there a similar way to explicitly 'reset' an iostream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What API are you using?  How is it using the stream?

Comment: libcURL. The stream is passed as an option to the cURL handle before calling 'perform' and is filled with the HTTP response.

Comment: What's an "iostream instance"? An fstream?

Comment: @Casey: "an instance of an iostream", also "an iostream". Ex: `std::iostream my_stream;`

Comment: Apparently I'm an idiot, I'd convinced myself that `std::iostream` was abstract. I'll shut up now.

Comment: I'd say an `iostream` itself doesn't manage data, it uses a streambuf (derived from `basic_streambuf`). You could swap out this streambuf (`std::basic_iostream::swap` is protected, though). `basic_streambuf` doesn't offer a `clear` function AFAIK, it's too abstract.

Comment: @Casey: You are in fact correct, at least mostly. Even though `std::iostream` is listed in the spec as concrete class with a public constructor, there is no way to create an `std::iostream` without an underlying stream buffer object. I'm moving to a `std::stringstream` implementation and calling it good. The other option is to create my own stream class based on `std::iostream` but that's overkill in this case. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You can instantiate `std::iostream` if you use the constructor that accepts a `streambuf*`, but yeah, implementing your own streambuf is not fun.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a `std::stringstream`. `std::iostream` objects are to abstracted for impelmentation.